# как перехватить CTRL+C в bat файле?

Tags: windows, bat

Подскажите как на Винде в bat файле можно перехватить нажатие CTRL+C и выполнить после этого что-то другое. Для баша я использую Trap, а вот как такое же сделать в батнике не знаю..

Пример реализации в баше:

```
#!/bin/bash
function trapsucsess {

        echo "Действие после CTRL+C"
}

count=0

trap trapsucsess 2

while [ $count -lt 100 ]
do
sleep 1
(( count++ ))
echo $count
done
```

Comment: Это встроеная фича, значит обход получится только  внешними средствами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291284/handle-ctrlc-on-win32